# Is there any way to link external html without the use of php

Tags: html, firebase

I am trying to link and external HTML file i used to be able to do it with php like this

```
   <?php include"sup.html"; ?>
```

can someone please help me

Comment: check this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

Comment: FWIW, the feature @Deryck is suggesting is unlikely to get good support anytime soon, and has been a source of new XSS attack vectors.

Comment: true dat.  be like everyone else and use Javascript and/or templates like https://lodash.com/docs#template